# How do I leverage Microsoft.Graph to update Autopilot information?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, maui, .net-7.0

I am trying to update an Autopilot device's information, though, I am receiving the error:

```
Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError
  Message=Exception of type 'Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError' was thrown.
```

I think it has to do with the request body "updateParameters", but I don't know what I have formatted incorrectly or written incorrectly to get this error. The only documentation I have to go off of is the NuGet's definition and this documentation here: [WindowsAutoPilotDeviceIdentity.UpdateDeviceProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/intune-enrollment-windowsautopilotdeviceidentity-updatedeviceproperties?view=graph-rest-1.0)

The code I've written is as follows to make this error appear:

```
public async Task<bool> UpdateAutopilotDeviceAsync(string managedDeviceId, UpdateDevicePropertiesPostRequestBody updateParameters)
        {
            if (_graphServiceClient == null)
            {
                await SignInAndInitializeGraphServiceClient();
            }
            try
            {
//LINE THROWING ERROR HERE
                await _graphServiceClient.DeviceManagement.WindowsAutopilotDeviceIdentities[managedDeviceId].UpdateDeviceProperties.PostAsync(updateParameters);
//LINE THROWING ERROR HERE
                return await Task.FromResult(true);
            }
            catch { }
```

```
        private async void Save_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string managedDeviceId = Device.ManagedDeviceId;

            UpdateDevicePropertiesPostRequestBody updateParameters = new()
            {
                UserPrincipalName = Device.UserPrincipalName,
                AddressableUserName = Device.AddressableUserName,
                GroupTag = Device.GroupTag,
                DisplayName = Device.DisplayName
            };

            await PublicClientSingleton.Instance.MSGraphHelper.UpdateAutopilotDeviceAsync(managedDeviceId, updateParameters);
        }
```

Stacktrace received is :

```
[   0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF in Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.monodroid_debugger_unhandled_exception C#
    0x1A in Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper._unhandled_exception at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:12,5 C#
    0x1D in Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PP_V at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:23,26    C#
    0x17 in System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw    C#
    0x6 in System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__128_0 C#
    0xC in Android.App.SyncContext. at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.App/SyncContext.cs:36,19 C#
    0xE in Java.Lang.Thread.RunnableImplementor.Run at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Java.Lang/Thread.cs:36,6 C#
    0x8 in Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/net7.0/android-33/mcw/Java.Lang.IRunnable.cs:84,4    C#
    0x8 in Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PP_V at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:22,5  C#
]
```

Comment: which line throws the exception?  What does the stack trace show?

Comment: Amended question with stack trace and commented around line throwing the error.

Comment: As far as I can see, the Microsoft.Graph NuGet Package might not work with .Net Maui.

Comment: @mrhls2312 Any chance you are able to extract the api error by using the guidance at the link below?  https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/feature/5.0/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md#error-handling

Comment: @Eastman That did the trick in identifying the error. I was receiving a "ResourceNotFound" error. I reviewed the resource and confirmed the guid was right, but it wasn't the right guid to be supplied. The managedDeviceId was being supplied when the api was needing the Autopilot Id (Device.Id vs. Device.managedDeviceId). Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Glad to hear it @mrhls2312! Posting the earlier comment as an answer as well if that's okay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Catching the API error and logging it should give more details on what the ODataError is.

```cs
try
{
    await graphServiceClient.Me.PatchAsync(user);
}
catch (ODataError odataError)
{
    Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Code);
    Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Message);
    throw;
}
```